# vue after $emit callback finished

Tags: vue.js, emit

In the compoent ,when call `$emit('callback', params)` finished, I need the returned value. Someone can help?

vueComponent:

```
    methods: {
        test: function () {
            if(this.$emit('cb', param1)){
                // this not working
                console.log('return true')
            }else{
                console.log('return false')
            }
        }
    }
```

vueRoot:

```
methods: {
        cb: function () {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$emit` only tells the parent component that an event has occurred and allows it to do something in response to the event and any data sent with it. The child component has no way of knowing what the results of the parent's actions are. In order to tell the child component something after the callback finishes, you will need to send that value through a `prop` and have the child `watch` for any changes to the prop's value.

Comment: @B.Fleming - You should post that as an answer!  :)

Comment: @PatrickSteele I had originally answered here with a comment in case someone else wanted to expand on the subject by detailing additional options like Vuex. Seeing as there are no other answers since then, however, I've opted to take your advice and formally submit it as an answer as well for the sake of visibility :)

Comment: Question Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74722761/4393351

Comment: We can pass the prop as function. check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74722761/4393351

Answer (score 8):

As per my comment below the original question, `$emit` only tells the parent component that an event has occurred and allows it to do something in response to the event and any data sent with it. The child component has no way of knowing what the results of the parent's actions are. In order to tell the child component something after the callback finishes, you will need to send that value through a `prop` and have the child `watch` for any changes to the prop's value.

Comment: Is it possible if I defined the prop as a function?

Comment: Could you add an example?

Comment: IMHO this is the right answer for how to do this. I see a lot of people using `this.$refs` to grab a child component, but I'm not sure this is always best practice. Seems like best practice is to update a prop of a child component, then have a watcher which triggers whatever method you're after. At least this seems to be the general mindset.

Comment: @twknab That's correct. While direct references occasionally have their place, they're seldom ever a good idea when dealing with communication between components. A child component shouldn't be imposing restrictions on how a parent component handles its events, and a parent component shouldn't care about the underlying implementation of the child component. Interfacing between them should be kept as simple as possible: the child reacts to changes in provided data and alerts the parent of events, and the parent reacts to any events and alerts the child of any changes in provided data.