# Is it possible to execute $emit as synchronous mode and get the result back from emit event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, emit

Is it possible to execute as emit as synchronous and get the result back in calling method itself. So, I want to execute next statement after the $emit completed. its as below:

```
Parent component has method, 
                 doCustomValidation();

child component is as follow:
methods:
{
  Save: function(){
 // Can I get the response here from parent component and then, execute 
    doGenericValidation ?

 var errorFields = this.$emit('custom-validation');  
   doGenericValidation(errorFields);   //this is generic validations
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldnt attempt to make this synchronous. Instead, you might be able to use this idea:

```
methods: {
    myMethod() {
        // Pass a function as a parameter.
        this.$emit('custom-validation', this.onComplete);
    },
    onComplete() {
        // Do stuff after custom-validation has completed.
    }
}
```

And then in whichever component uses your event:

```
<some-component @custom-validation="doStuff" />
<script>
...
methods: {
    doStuff(done) {
        // Your logic here. After that, call the callback function.
        done();
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass data on this,  this.$emit('custom-validation(data)', this.onComplete(resultFromChild));  ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it accepts multiple parameters, if not you could just do `this.$emit('custom-validation', {data: data, callback: this.onComplete})` and you will now receive an object as the parameter

Comment: There might be multiple listeners attached to an event (or none). As a result, the `onComplete()` callback might be called multiple times, or not at all with this approach

Comment: @igaster yep you're right, I guess you can shape some sort of `once` function such that the callback can only be executed once. It doesnt sound like a nice solution to be honest but then again events always allow multiple listeners.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a promise based wrapper for emit and wait for its result.

Here is a pretty generic solution I've ended up creating for my projects:

```
    async emitPromised(method, ...params){
        let listener = this.$listeners[method] || this.$attrs[method] || this[method]
        if(listener){
            let res = await listener(...params)
            return res === undefined || res
        }
        return false
    },
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
        async onDelete(){
            this.isDeleting = true
            let res = await this.emitPromised("delete")
            this.isDeleting = false
            if(res){
                this.closeConfirm()
            }
        },
```

You can include this method through mixin or attach it globally to Vue instance so it's accessible to all components.

As a note, `$listeners` store all methods bound to this component with `@` or `v-on` (like `<MyComponet @click="onClick"/>`) while `$attrs` store everything passed to the component using `v-bind` or `:` (like `<MyComponet :click="onClick"/>`)

Comment: simple, clear and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

No.  `$emit` will always be queued.  There also may be multiple listeners, so a return value does not really make sense.

As a workaround, you can send a function in as a property, and then call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem statement, where I have my validations method in parent and wants to check that in child component, before performing the save action.

If you want to perform something like this. then a better option is to pass the method as props. It may not make sense to await for the response of `$emit`.

**Example:**

The method that I need to call is `doCustomValidation().` of parent-component from child-component's `save()` method.

**Parent Codebase (shown only the required codebase where names matching to the asked question):**

```
<template>
    <child-component
      :doCustomValidation="doCustomValidation"
    />
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import ChildComponent from "@/students/ChildComponent.vue";

export default defineComponent({
    components: { 
        "child-component": ChildComponent,
    },
    methods: { 
        doCustomValidation() { 
           let isValid = false;
           // do your stuff here, even you can access the 
           // validation params and show the validations here.
           return isValid;
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

**Child Codebase (shown only the required codebase where names matching to the asked question):**

```
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent({
  props: ["doCustomValidation"],
  methods: { 
      save() {
         // calling parent validation method and 
         // this will wait for result.
         if(this.doCustomValidation()) {
            // perform Save here.
         }
      }
  }
)}
</script>
```